# How to skip rest of the .then & return the data to caller

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I want to skip all the .then after a particular .then. But this particular .then will need to return a data to the caller.

```
function test() {    
    return User.findOne({ where: potentialUser })
        .then(function(user) { // level-1
            if(!user) {
                return { // data-1
                    status: 404,
                    json: { message: 'Not a valid user.' }
                };
            } else {
                return anyValidPromise;
            }
        })
        .then(function(isMatch) { // level-2

        })
        .then(function(val) { // level-3

        })
        .then(function(val) {

        })
        .then(function(val) {

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return {
                status: 500,
                json: { message: 'There was an error!' }
            };
        });
}
```

Now according to the above example level-1 must return data-1 to the caller of test. And all the .then from level-2 will not be executed.

Is it possible to achieve this?

If all the .then are executed then the caller is getting the data which is being returned at the last level of .then.

Comment: The "caller" is just another `then` on the chain. There's no way to do that with a linear chain.

Comment: @Bergi there has always a way. Check the selected answer.

Comment: Yes - one that uses nesting. You should definitely avoid abusing exceptions for ordinary control flow.

Answer (score 1):

One of Promises advantages is "flattening" of the pyramid of doom

But sometimes, the required logic requires a certain level of "nesting"

This is one such case

```
function test() {    
    return User.findOne({ where: potentialUser })
    .then(function(user) { // level-1
        if(!user) {
            return { // data-1
                status: 404,
                json: { message: 'Not a valid user.' }
            };
        } else {
            return anyValidPromise
            .then(function(isMatch) { // level-2

            })
            .then(function(val) { // level-3

            })
            .then(function(val) {

            })
            .then(function(val) {

            })
        }
    )
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        return {
            status: 500,
            json: { message: 'There was an error!' }
        };
    });
}
```

> Refactoring, you could do something like (I don't really like this by the way)

```
function test() {    
    let level4 = bar => {
        if(bar) {
            return {};
        } else {
            return {};
        }
    }
    let level3 = foo => {
        if(foo) {
            return {};
        } else {
            return level4(bar);
        }
    }
    let level2 = isMatch => {
        if(isMatch) {
            return {};
        } else {
            return level3(foo);
        }
    }
    let level1 = user => {
        if(!user) {
            return { // data-1
                status: 404,
                json: { message: 'Not a valid user.' }
            };
        } else {
            return anyValidPromise.then(level2)
        }
    };
    return User.findOne({ where: potentialUser })
    .then(level1)
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        return {
            status: 500,
            json: { message: 'There was an error!' }
        };
    });
}
```

Not sure if that is at all helpful though, your original code is "sparse" :p

Another possibility is to abuse the promise rejection chain for your own nefarious means

```
function test() {    
    return User.findOne({ where: potentialUser })
    .then(function(user) { // level-1
        if(!user) {
            throw { // data-1
                status: 404,
                json: { message: 'Not a valid user.' },
                skip: true
            };
        } else {
            return anyValidPromise;
        }
    })
    .then(function(isMatch) { // level-2
        if (youWantToSkipFromHere) {
            throw {
                status: ???
                json: ???
                skip: true
            };
        }
    })
    // etc etc
    .then(function(val) { // level-3
        if (youWantToSkipFromHere) {
            throw {
                status: ???
                json: ???
                skip: true
            };
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        if (error.skip) {
            return error;
        }
        console.log(error);
        return {
            status: 500,
            json: { message: 'There was an error!' }
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Then it may happen all the .then level got nestings. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Possibly by refactoring your code, but really depends on specifics

Comment: Is it possible to help me by refactoring the above code?

Comment: I've added a third possibility - this time with no nesting

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal If you want to get no nesting through `then` callbacks, use `await` syntax instead.

Comment: @Bergi Im using the third option of Jaromanda and its working well. Do you think it will make problem in future?

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal With that duck-typing `skip` property it should at least work even in light of other errors, but yes I would recommend to avoid it. It's much less efficient than nesting, and doing control flow with exceptions is like programming with goto.

Comment: @Bergi you are right. async/await is much more cleaner than Promise nesting. Can you answer here. I need to change the selected answer.